# AsyncTask to avoid NetworkOnMainThread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, networkonmainthread

How can i send different Type Arguments to the AsyncTask.

I am developing Login System in android using J Son/php. I got NetworkOnMainThread Exception and i was suggested to implement AsyncTask in my code. I need to send URL in string and List. How can i send this to the functions?? These values are sending from other class.

```
public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String,Void,JSONObject>
```

I don't know whether i am correct or not.
Hoping response.

here is my modification done

```
private String url;
private List<NameValuePair> params;
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

    return getJsonFromURL(url,params);
}

void callJson(String url,List<NameValuePair> params){
   this.url=url;
    this.params=params;
}
```

I am calling AsyncTask like this way:

```
jsonParser=new JSONParser();
    jsonParser.setter(LoginUrl, username,password);
    try {
        jsonObject= jsonParser.execute("").get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;
```

Now am getting this error.

```
2843-2858/? E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value loginRegistration of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
    01-07 10:04:09.808    2843-2843/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: artha.ordermaking.KOT, PID: 2843
        java.lang.NullPointerException
                at 

    ex.WelcomeActivity$PlaceholderFragment.loginProcess(WelcomeActivity.java:84)
                    at ex.WelcomeActivity$PlaceholderFragment$1.onClick(WelcomeActivity.java:118)
```

Note that I have changed my code submitted above.

Comment: you can create a constructor in your asynctask to pass more data to it, for example.

Comment: I tried my level best.But still got Exception.

Comment: If you have problems with your code, consider including relevant parts to the question, with exception stacktrace from logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should invoke your async task with `execute()` and not by directly calling the `doInBackground()` method on it in the UI thread, as evidenced by the stacktrace:

```
at artha.ordermaking.KOT.library.JSONParser.doInBackground(JSONParser.java:36)
at artha.ordermaking.KOT.library.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:37)
```

From comments:

> jsonObject=jsonParser.execute(); Its not working. I need to get JSONObject. execute() is returning AsyncTask Object.

That would not be an *async* task if you waited for its completion.

Instead, do all processing in `doInBackground()` and update your UI in `onPostExecute()` which has access to the `doInBackground()` result. This update can also involve calling a callback method in your UI code.

In your updated question:

> ```
> jsonObject= jsonParser.execute("").get();
> ```

`get()` is the wrong solution. It blocks the current thread (UI thread) until the async task completes. So you're back where you started from: preventing a network operation to block the UI thread.

Comment: jsonObject=jsonParser.execute(); Its not working. I need to get JSONObject. execute() is returning AsyncTask Object.

Comment: how to get Returned JSONObject??

Comment: In `onPostExecute()` arg or store in a member var.

Answer (score 0):

The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:

> The first, Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon
>   execution. The second, Progress, the type of the progress units
>   published during the background computation. The third, Result, the
>   type of the result of the background computation.

If you need to pass additional data to your AsyncTask, simply create a method which receives that data in your AsyncTask and call it within the main UI. For example:

```
public void setMyHandler(Handler h) { myhandler = h; }
```

You'll be able to find more info on the AsyncTask help page, [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Constructor` in your `AsyncTask` class and can fetch the data into it.

The parameters are the following `AsyncTask <TypeOfVarArgParams , ProgressValue , ResultValue> .`

`TypeOfVarArgParams` is passed into the `doInBackground()` method as input, `ProgressValue` is used for progress information and `ResultValue` must be returned from `doInBackground()` method and is passed to `onPostExecute(`) as a parameter.

How ever you can find this tutorial very helpful for learning this topic. Here is the tutorial [Android Background Processing with Handlers and AsyncTask and Loaders - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class contain all your necessary data, and use that class as parameter to AsyncTask.
Or if AsyncTask parameter annoying you, you can use runOnUiThread and thread:

```
class Login implements Runnable{
    public Login(parameters...){    
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
            //Login
            runOnUiThread(new LoginResult(params...));
    }
}

class LoginResult implements Runnable{
    public Login(parameters...){    
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
}
```

....

```
new Thread(new Login()).start();
```

Comment: incorrect. runOnUiThread runs on ui thread, which defeats the purpose of not running on the ui thread.

Answer (score -1):

Quite simple way to avoid NetworkOnMainThreadException

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
        .permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

put these lines into your `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method of the Activity